# Java. Долгое получение данных с ResultSet mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

Я столкнулся с проблемой, когда создаю Statement (connection.createStatement()..) и пытаюсь получить данные:

```
ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM database WHERE chat_id = 1");
rs.next();
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
String test = rs.getString("test");
System.out.println("Выполнено за: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms");
// то результат может быть от 150мс до 40 секунд, что очень медленно (иногда 1, 3 мс)
```

А если не создавать Statement, и использовать уже созданный в начале работы кода, то результат от 1 до 5 мс (больше 50 не видел), но может возникнуть ошибка: `ResultSet is closed`

Как правильно сделать, при этом сохраняя высокую скорость получаения данных? Т.к у меня бот ВКонтакте, и ему почти на каждое сообщение необходимо обращаться к базе. (драйвер jdbc)

Comment: А подключение откуда берется? тоже на каждое обращение - новый connection?

Comment: @kami нет, подключение делается один раз только в начале работы кода.

Comment: Попробуйте https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html